# Typescript merge tuples

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How to merge tuples together? I need to add one tuple after end of another like below.

```
type MergeTuple<A extends any[], B extends any[]> = [...A, ...B];
```

Only thing that works is this:

```
type MergeTuple<A extends any[], B extends any[]> = [A[0], B[0]];
```

But that works with static count of items

```
MergeTuple<['a'], ['b']> // is ['a', 'b']
```

Not working for this

```
MergeTuple<['a', 'b'], ['c']> // is ['a', 'c'] expected ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: you don't need Tuple types if you will use *any*

Comment: it doesn't need to extend any[] ... that's my defintion of a type.. i am just saying type is tuple

Answer (score 5):

Concatenating Tuples in TS is currently just possible with very ugly workarounds.

[Here is how one library does it](https://github.com/ksxnodemodules/typescript-tuple/blob/92f121f1ef10b15bbcd514b763d2ebb3643fcd5f/lib/utils.ts#L287-L303)

You don't want to do that yourself. Ask yourself if you *really* need that, and if the answer is yes, do yourself the favor and use a type library like `typescript-tuple`.

Answer (score 1):

Does this not work for you?

```js
type MergeTuples<
    A extends readonly any[],
    B extends readonly any[]
> = [...A, ...B];
```

Here is a [playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBYgzw) if needed.